# Spring app tries to recreate the DB on each run instead of updating

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a small Spring Boot app and Postgresql database. I want to use JPA to leverage JpaRepository and I'm now writing the `schema.sql` to initialize the DB which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE historical_prices
(
id float NOT NULL,
date_time varchar(100),
rate float NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

My application properties is configured as follows:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cryptodb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=akljevnc983iu4fneciu3infejc

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Yet each time I run the app I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/crypto/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE historical_prices ( id float NOT NULL, date_time varchar(100), rate float NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "historical_prices" already exists
```

Why does it say `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "historical_prices" already exists` if I'm setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`?

I've also tried with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` but still no luck.

Is there a way to omit this creation step without removing the DDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) :

> Spring Boot automatically creates the schema of an embedded
> `DataSource`. This behavior can be customized by using the
> `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` property (and it can also be
> `always` or `never`).

You should set the property to `never`.

Answer (score 2):

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto**: turn off the hibernate auto-creation of the tables from the entity objects. Generally, Hibernate runs it if there is an Entity defined. But you will be using a native SQL query with JdbcTemplate, hence, you can turn this off as you will not be creating an Entity.

**spring.datasource.initialization-mode** : is marked as always as we want initialization of the database to happen on every startup.

So maybe you should not initialize the database after each startup.

use *spring.datasource.initialization-mode = never*